# Laravel 5 Multiple Fields Validation

Tags: validation, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I have a field in the view the go something like

```html
<div>
  <input type="text" name="new[0][description]" id="description-new-0">
  <input type="text" name="new[0][amount]" id="amount-new-0">
</div>

<div>
  <input type="text" name="new[1][description]" id="description-new-1">
  <input type="text" name="new[1][amount]" id="amount-new-1">
</div>
```

and so on... so you can imagine that its a dynamic field that adds in the form every time you tick the add button or whatever.

The question is how can I VALIDATE these dynamic fields and will return the right error for each fields?

Thanks!

Note this is Laravel 5 but if you have a Laravel 4 solution similar to this one I guess(really guess) it will work.

Thanks guys!

Comment: You should be able to use dot notation to access the nested array items during valuation, so create your rules for `new.description` and `new.amount`

Answer (score 7):

create in folder Requests validator for this form like

```
<?php
use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class MultipleRequest extends FormRequest
{

    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        $rules = [
            'description' => 'required|array',
        ];

        if ($this->request->get('description')) {
            foreach($this->request->get('description') as $key => $val)
            {
                $rules['description.'.$key] = 'required|min:7'; //example
            }
        }

        return $rules;
    }


    public function messages()
    {
        $messages = [];
        if ($this->request->get('description')) {
            foreach ($this->request->get('description') as $key => $val) {
                $messages['description.' . $key . '.min'] = 'Wrong field.';
                $messages['description.' . $key . '.required'] = 'This field required.';
            }
        }
        return $messages;
    }
}
```

more info [How To: Validate an array of form fields with Laravel](http://ericlbarnes.com/laravel-array-validation/)

then in view do the next

```
@if (Session::has('_old_input'))
        @for ($i=0; $i<count(Session::get('_old_input.description')); $i++)
            <div>
                @if($errors->any() && Session::get('errors')->getBag('default')->has('description.' . $i))
                    <p class="">{{Session::get('errors')->getBag('default')->first('description.' . $i)}}</p>
                @endif


                <input type="text" name="new[][description]" id="description-new-{{$i}}" value="{{Session::get('_old_input.description.' . $i)}}">
                <input type="text" name="new[][amount]" id="amount-new-{{$i}}" value="{{Session::get('_old_input.amount.' . $i)}}">
            </div>
        @endfor
    @endif
```

so you add block with error message for each block with inputs. In my example only description processed, amount you can processed similar description
For my it works and look like 
[image]

**UPD:**
Laravel version 5.2 has array validation so you can create request validator like:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'names.*' => 'required|max:50',
        'emails.*' => 'required|max:100',
    ];
}
```

for more info read [DOC](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/validation#validating-arrays)